# Testing Question in Selenium Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

How to get required item *hrefs* in a flipkart page?

**This is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path ="/home/yegaiah/Desktop/geckodriver") 
website_URL ="https://www.amazon.in/s?bbn=3403635031&rh=n%3A1984443031%2Cn%3A%211984444031%2Cn%3A3403635031%2Cn%3A3403933031%2Cp_89%3AAmazonBasics%2Cp_6%3AAT95IG9ONZD7S&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=6637738031&pf_rd_m=A1K21FY43GMZF8&pf_rd_p=3eb96131-76ce-41f7-9b72-4f5d8f986b21&pf_rd_r=M9KP9AE8GV7B4SS91K9M&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-7&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1542006913&rnid=3403635031&suppress-ve=1&ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_abcatnav_9a1_w"
driver.get(website_URL)
myLinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
links = []
for link in myLinks:
    url = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(url)
```

As this code was printing all *hrefs* in the flipkart page, but I need only some required items of *hrefs* only.

Comment: Fix your question, format your code, dont shout, what error you get, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can select *WebElement*'s by using list comprehension with a filtering.
For instance, if you want to select only links that have the ***Required*** text, you would:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
required_links = [ link for link in links if "Required" in link.text]
```

The list comprehension says the following:

"Construct a new **list** made of each **link** in the **links list** if the **text in this link** has the **Required** sub-string"

If you have a different criteria, you just need to change the part after ***if***.